# What is the library responsible for showing the query in a different color in Android Studio and monitoring the error when writing the query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am making a database ROM project in Android Studio
But when writing the query, it does not appear in a different color and also does not see the name of the table
I suspect that there is a lack of a library in the gradle file
Or is there a problem otherwise

I suspect that there is a lack of a library responsible for query monitoring
But I don't know what it is?

Comment: Pretty sure it’s just built into the Room library. You might have some setting disabled.

Comment: Search for "language injections" in Android studio - Editor settings. I have an item called "Room Query annotation" there